# Should a toggle switch's label be on its left or right?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, toggle

[image]

Which is more appropriate or more commonly used? Toggle switch labels on its right or on its left?

Answer (score 13):

Labels on either side serve different purposes.

In reading order,
Labels **before** the switch (on the **left or top** for LTR languages) indicate ***what the switch is for***.
Labels **after** the switch (on the **right or bottom** for LTR) optionally indicate ***the state of the switch***.

Here's an example from Windows 10:

[image: Windows 10 Toggle Switches]

When you can't afford space, you can wrap the items without affecting the left-to-right-top-to-bottom reading order, as you see with the first 'Notifications' section of switches in the image above.

Windows 8 mobile also follows this approach, but wraps the state text to a new line for lack of space to the right of the button.

[image: Windows 8 Mobile Toggle Switches]

The opposite conventions would be applicable for a RTL language.

Answer (score 1):

In English, I have almost always seen the Label, followed by the Toggle switch. I'm not sure if this would be the same in interfaces using languages that are not read left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Its really vary upon different languages like LTR and RTL format
Two kind of writing and reading format used :
 **LTR(Left to Right)** and **RTL(right to left)**.
**Urdu/Arabic** and **Hebrew** letter are RTL apart form that worlds all languages are going under LRT.

These above things are not main concern actually the concern things is about  Cognitive Science and our mind set. you can see the example  bellow two same page but in different language (English and Hebrew)

[image]

I can convey my communication in three language and all are from LTR, so its hard to set my mind to see the things from RTL.
if you working for LTR languages like English then, i will suggest to better use right toggle switch

Answer (score 0):

To answer straight labels should be "**Right side**".

[image: Toggle Switch Label]

Comment: In your example, 'Storage sense' is also a label, and technically it appears to the left/top of the button in reading order. It would help if you elaborate your answer.

Comment: In your example, what do you mean by "straight labels"? When it's just on/off and not text that's longer?